# Deploy Coldfusion to Heroku

Tags: heroku, coldfusion

Is there any way to deploy a Coldfusion app to Heroku using Windows or Mac? I just found the [following way](https://github.com/mikesprague/lucee-heroku-template), but unfortunately it's already deprecated.

Any idea would help me a lot!

Regards

Comment: "Deprecated in favor of the Lucee 5 version" Did you try the Lucee 5 version? https://github.com/mikesprague/lucee5-heroku/blob/master/README.md